# Spring Cache - Not caching based on parameter

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, junit

Hello StackOverFlow Community,

I'm working with Spring @Cacheable and adding a parameter to the key as below,

```
@Cacheable(value = "task-status", key = "'get-by-visibility-'+#visible")
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM prefix_taskstatus WHERE visible=:visible")
public List<TaskStatus> getByVisibility(@Param("visible") Boolean visible);
```

I created a JUnit test as below,

```
@Test
public void test() {
    _logger.info(">> test()");

    _logger.info(taskStatusRepo.getByVisibility(true).size());
    _logger.info(taskStatusRepo.getByVisibility(false).size());
    _logger.info(taskStatusRepo.getByVisibility(true).size());
    _logger.info(taskStatusRepo.getByVisibility(false).size());

    _logger.info("<< test()");
}
```

The output of the JUnit test is as below,

```
INFO: >> test()
Hibernate: 
    SELECT * FROM prefix_taskstatus WHERE visible=?
INFO: 10
INFO: 10
INFO: 10
INFO: 10
INFO: << test()
```

I'm loading the necessary cache config from an application context file using the below,

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet-application-context.xml" })
```

And the portlet-application-context.xml has the below declaration,

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="some-name" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And running the JUnit test using the below annotation,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

The parameter with 'false' isn't being fetched from the database. What am I missing here?

Comment: where is your configuration class of spring cache ? and did you load that config class from test code?

Comment: Yes. I'm loading the necessary cache config from an application context file